# Using Node.js is there a way to reverse return values from true to false or visa versa?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Environment:** Node.js

**Question:** Is there a way to reverse return values from `true` to `false` or visa versa?

**Example:**

In the simple code block below I use `Mongoose` to check if a user exists in a DB.  If the user exists it returns `true`, if not it returns `false`.  However I'm using this to see if an email is available for use because it's not already in use by another user.  I can write an extra line of code that turns `true` into `false` but is there a shorthand I can use to make that happen without the extra line?  Putting `!` in front of User.exists doesn't seem to do it.

```
let isEmailAvailable = await User.exists({ email });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To win an extra line, you need to wrap `await User.exists({ email })` inside parentheses and add `!` in front of it:

```js
let isEmailAvailable = !(await User.exists({ email }));
```

Comment: Brilliant, tested and worked!  I'll use that pattern for a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to put `!` in front of it.

```js
function UserExists() {
   return true;
}

console.log(UserExists())
let isEmailAvailable = !UserExists();
console.log(isEmailAvailable)
```

Just look into above example, UserExists Function returning the `true` to `false`.

---

*Update:* with Async Function

```js
    
    function UserExists() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(true);
        }, 500);
      });
    }

    async function testAsync() {
      console.log(await UserExists())
      let isEmailAvailable = !(await UserExists());
      console.log(isEmailAvailable)      
    }
    
    testAsync();
```

Comment: Dang that may work on my own function but the `!` doesn't seem to work when applied to the Mongoose function `Document.exists()`.

Comment: It's happening because of the async method, I updated my answer to work with async.

Answer (score 1):

You can let as is but if you will use the variable you can add an !

For example :

```
let isEmailAvailable = await User.exists({ email });

if (!isEmailAvailable) {
    // Do what you want if user do not exist
}
```